# EMBER.JS Define models if I only need to read?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

Is there any utility in defining models in Ember if I am only going to read from the server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes there is. Modelling your frontend to be similar to the  backend will always be helpful.
The plus points I can think of are

1. Hassle free handling of relationships.
2. Caching of results in the store would save on server calls.
3. Writing back to the server becomes easy if you suddenly need that.
4. Selective data loading with the {async:true} option in relationships. Load only what you need.

Check out this link http://emberjs.com/blog/2014/03/18/the-road-to-ember-data-1-0.html for more information.